# What is the real name of those rivet-like plastic fasteners?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners

I'm trying to find the name of a removable fastener operating by a deforming retainer in the front like in the picture:

[[image: example fastener with a spring]

All I found online are Alibaba and similar listings that don't seem to contain any keywords uniquely identifying this particular type of the device.

Comment: Naming things is a significant problem in mechanical engineering. Do we really want to go here?

Comment: It looks like a specialty push-lock pin, other than the manufacturer that uses it in his product, I don't think there is a commercial name for it.

Comment: Quarter turn panel fastener, spring loaded self eject.

Answer (score 2):

Anti-rattle clips

spring-loaded pins

spring loaded toggle pins

spring loaded twist pins

Are some possibilities, but there are probably others.

Answer (score 2):

"Spring loaded fastener" is another possibility

Answer (score 2):

Snap-in captive screw is another similar term